# removing comma from number in sybase

Tags: parsing, sap-ase

i have this morning an issue with 1 field. In particular i have a number with decimal separation that is not expected. E.G -98,060;
sometime the numbers are without the comma so -2032; -3452; etc. How can i update below query so that i can replace number with -98,060; like this -98060 ?

thank you

```
CONVERT(NUMERIC(20,6),SUBSTRING(case when rtrim(ltrim(tab1.comment)) is not null

then tab1.comment else '0;0' end,1,(CHARINDEX(';',case when rtrim(ltrim(tab1.comment)) is not null

then tab1.comment else '0;0' end)-1))) as COMMENT,
```

The above logic currently transform the value from -24556; to -24556 without ";"

Now that i have -98,060; so a value with a command inside the above formula crashed. How can i update above formula so that after the transformation of number like this -98,060; i have -98060 ? thank you

Comment: just to be clear, the requirement isn't to remove a comma from a number, the requirement is to remove a comma from a string where the comma shows up between some numeric characters; I'm assuming (???) that the `comment` column may contain some commas that you do not want to remove otherwise you could use the same `substring/charindex` logic to remove the comma ... yes? no?

Comment: Hi Markp-fuso, thanks for your comment. Currently " ; " that is after the numbers are already removed considering above code. The current logic working only for INT numbers without decimal. So my needs is to convert decimal numbers as integer numbers without any " , "   EG: from -24,556; to -24556 in order to avoid issue during the conversion.

Comment: which Sybase RDBMS (ASE? IQ? SQLAnywhere? Advantage?) and version?

Comment: Sybase ASE 16 yes

Comment: without a complete set of sample data, I'm going to assume you want to strip out **all** commas from the `comment` column in which case you may want to try `str_replace(tab1.comment,",",NULL)`; taking into consideration latest comment ... once you've stripped out the 'number' you should still be able to use `str_replace()` to strip out the comma before converting to a numeric

Comment: Right thanks you is working: str_replace(tab1.comment,",",NULL) - only one other thing, in the end i have " ; " how can i remove it ?

Comment: if there are no semi-colons you wish to keep, then you should be able to use `str_replace(source_string,';',NULL)`

Comment: thank you so much markp-fuso!! Have a great day!! :)